# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list - JS

Tags: javascript

I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Here is my JS code

```
$('#product_price .price').html('<span class="money"><strong>'Sale Price: + Shopify.formatMoney(variant.price, "${{amount}} USD") + '</strong></span>');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `Sale Price:` ? hint: its not a string.

Comment: You have unclosed parentheses near `strong>'Sale `.

Comment: move your quote: `('<span class="money"><strong>Sale Price:'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$('#product_price .price').html('<span class="money"><strong>Sale Price:' + Shopify.formatMoney(variant.price, "${{amount}} USD") + '</strong></span>');
```